# issue with url of action in zend framework1

Tags: zend-framework

I created a local php project:zf-tutorial,now the main url is : `http://localhost/zf-tutorial/public/`

Then I created an action using command: zf create action add Index, now I got another url for this action: `http://localhost/zf-tutorial/public/index/add`

Question:

why it is `http://localhost/zf-tutorial/public/index/add` not `http://localhost/zf-tutorial/public/add`? is there a way that I can change "add" action url to `http://localhost/zf-tutorial/public/add`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a controller named `AddController` and name the action `indexAction`, then you will get the url as `http://localhost/zf-tutorial/public/add`

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom URLs for your actions by using [Zend_Controller_Router](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html). Read through that documentation section to understand the all concept.

In your particular case I think [Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.static) might be the most suitable. Try to add this in your application's bootstrap:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static(
    'public/add',
    array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'add')
);
$router->addRoute('login', $route);
```